# Polyhedron from the plane equations

Tags: c++, c, graphics, geometry, computational-geometry

I have a few planes (3-10 of them) in 3d defined by their equations (three coefficients and the offset). These planes are the edges of a convex polyhedron. I need to draw that polyhedron. How can I do that? What software/libraries/algorithms can I use? I work in Linux and I'm usually using C or C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every plane pair intersects in a line on both planes. Each plane then contains a set of lines that intersect in points, all of those are the edge points of your polyhedron you'll have to connect in a convex way.

With some math/geometry skills, you should be able to solve this, but using a library (f.e. [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/)) of course simplifies it and prevent you from reinventing the wheel.